# Is there any Kafka Connector that would enable to read XML content into KAFKA?

Tags: xml, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Is there any Kafka Connector that would enable to read XML content into KAFKA. I have a folder in which a very large set of XML Files get send to continually coming from an upstream system. I wonder if there is a way to ingest them in KAFKA for stream processing with Apache Spark.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your need you can try to use [Kafka Connect FilePulse](https://streamthoughts.github.io/kafka-connect-file-pulse/) for reading XML.

In addition, here are some blog posts about reading XML Files with Kafka:

- [Streaming data into Kafka S01/E02 - Loading XML file](https://dev.to/fhussonnois/streaming-data-into-kafka-s01-e02-loading-xml-file-529i)
- [ingesting-xml-data-into-kafka-introduction](https://rmoff.net/2020/10/01/ingesting-xml-data-into-kafka-introduction/)
- [ingesting-xml-data-into-kafka-option-1-the-dirty-hack](https://rmoff.net/2020/10/01/ingesting-xml-data-into-kafka-option-1-the-dirty-hack/)
- [ingesting-xml-data-into-kafka-option-2-kafka-connect-plus-single-message-transform](https://rmoff.net/2020/10/01/ingesting-xml-data-into-kafka-option-2-kafka-connect-plus-single-message-transform/)
- [ingesting-xml-data-into-kafka-option-3-kafka-connect-filepulse-connector](https://rmoff.net/2020/10/01/ingesting-xml-data-into-kafka-option-3-kafka-connect-filepulse-connector/)

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of Connect FilePulse*